# LPTHW Ex16.. Script is running but Text file not updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running the Ex16 script from LPTHW and the script runs fine till the end (including my inputs for writing 3 lines), but the text file is not getting updated. What could be the possible reasons? I'm running this script on Python3.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

print ("We're going to erase %r " % (filename))
print ("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print ("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input("?")

print ("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename,'w')

print ("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print ("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.")
line1 = input("line 1: ")
line2 = input("line 2: ")
line3 = input("line 3: ")

print ("I'm going to write these to the file.")
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
print ("And finally, we close it.")
target.close()
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me …

Comment: By the way, LPTHW is [not well regarded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=lpthw&room=6) as a Python learning resource. You might want to try [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) instead.

Comment: Are you using Python3 as well! For me, the text file is still not being overwritten

Comment: yep ... my guess would be that the file is getting written, but not in the folder you expect. A guess is all it is, though.

Comment: It was actually in different folder... Thanks!